# Touch ID window for sudo doesn't get focus when opened from iTerm

Tags: iterm, sudo, touch-id

I enabled Touch ID for sudo using `pam_tid.so`, the problem is whenever I run a sudo command in iTerm, the Touch ID window opens but it is not focused, like this:
[image]

and holding my finger on the touch sensor doesn't do anything, I have to first click on it with the mouse (can't even find a way to give it focus with the keyboard) and then it gains focus like this:

[image]

and then I can put my finger on the touch sensor to authorize it.

It is not the case for Terminal application, the problem only exists in iTerm.

Does anyone know how I can make it so it automatically gains focus?

P.S. It doesn't work regardless of the iTerm window being full screen or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, I have the same question, and I can not find a best answer in Google. A causal idea I just thought is close the `Secure Keyboard Entry` where is in `iTerm` tab, or shortcut `option+command+S`~

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I marked it as the accepted solution until we have a better solution.

Comment: This solution also works for Terminal.app

Comment: Tkx for your attention~